# Using same cookies with differents subdomains in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cookies

I have my main domain (http://www.domain.com) which is under Wordpress, and I created subdomains that link categories :

- http://one.domain.com => http://www.domain.com/category/one
- http://two.domain.com => http://www.domain.com/category/two
- ...

It works very well except for the persistent of cookies... I can not use functions such as **get_currentuserinfo()** or global variables such as **$user_ID**.

I tried this but it did not work :

```
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.domain.com');
```

Have you got any ideas please ? Thank you.

Comment: be sure to clear your cookies to see if that changes take effect.

Answer (score 1):

The wordpress.org site mentions different cookiepath constants, namely

```
define('COOKIEPATH', preg_replace('|https?://[^/]+|i', '', get_option('home') . '/' ) );
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', preg_replace('|https?://[^/]+|i', '', get_option('siteurl') . '/' ) );
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . 'wp-admin' );
define('PLUGINS_COOKIE_PATH', preg_replace('|https?://[^/]+|i', '', WP_PLUGIN_URL)  );
```

Have you tried those already? (You'd have to set your corresponding paths of course ;))

Source: [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Additional_Defined_Constants)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it does not work. When I look at the cookies the domain is still www.domain.com :s